# Ajax not going to url method

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter-3

This is the code for ajax request it always goes to error function.

The url is correct, all data is there, but it still goes to the error.  It is not posting the values.

```
$(".quote-update-notify").click(function () {
    //e.preventDefault();
    //alert('hi');
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    //alert(id);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>Admin/qoute_Notification",
        //                       
        //ataType: 'json',
        data: {"id": id},
        success: function () {
            alert('success');
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('error while requeting');
            //console.log();
        }
    });
    //e.preventDefault();
    //return false;
});
```

Comment: what is value in base_url();?

Comment: url is right i have checked that

Comment: If it goes to your error function, why not show the error? `error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { alert(textStatus + ': ' + errorThrown) }`

Comment: Alternatively, use your browser's *Network* console to inspect the request data and response for the failing request

Comment: @Phil ill try this

Comment: @Phil the alert is internal server error

Comment: So check your server's error log

Comment: I think you are missing the file extension. `qoute_Notification.php`

Comment: Try to use `<?php echo json_encode(base_url()); ?>+Admin/qoute_Notification`. I don't know if you are missing `.php` extension or just using rewrite engine. Good luck.

Comment: @Phil thanks ur right i solved that,its internal server error thanks again

Answer (score 0):

The issue may be from the url param:

Kindly do not pass the php tag in this param, instead check by hardcoding the url path properly.Once it is working, then try to fix this by getting base_url() value from the hidden id from the view page :

in view file:

```
<input class="furl" type="hidden" value="<?php echo base_url(); ?>"/>
```

in js :

```
var url = jQuery(".furl").val() + 'Action/qoute_Notification';
```